# How to make @SpringBootTest use application.properties from external config folder (inside project root)?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, spring-boot-test, application.properties

I have a **multi-module Spring Boot Gradle project (Kotlin)** with the following directory structure.

```
root
|- domain (Module containing entities and interfaces)
|- application (Spring boot Kotlin application)
    |- src/main
        |- kotlin (app sources)
        |- resources
        |- application.properties (default config)
    |- src/test/kotlin/long/package/name/ApplicationTests.kt
    |- build.gradle.kts (and also gradle folder)
|- config
    |- application.properties (config to override classpath properties)
|- build.gradle.kts (and settings.gradle.kts and other gradle folder)
```

When I run the `Application.kt` file, it is able to pick up this file (both with IDE and gradle), and it runs successfully.

Since my **config** folder is outside my **application** folder, running my `ApplicationTests.kt` results in the error below. The output is same when running through IDE (IntelliJ) run button and `./gradlew clean test`.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection
```

I am expecting the tests to find the `application.properties` file inside the config folder. How can I register my config/application.properties so that I can keep it separate from my `classpath:application.properties`?

**UPDATE:**
I tried adding the following copy task to gradle.

```
tasks.create("copy", Copy::class.java) {
    from("../config")
    into("$buildDir/resources/main")

}

tasks.named("test").configure {
    dependsOn("copy")
}
```

This enables me to overwrite the application.properties from config folder (meaning any property not added in config/app.prop is no longer present). Test runs successfully now (if I add all entries from classpath properties to config/app.props). How can I merge the contents of these two properties files inside `application/build.gradle.kts`?

Comment: file inside the config folder find the application.properties expecting the tests to register config/application.properties

Comment: sorry I didn’t understand?

Answer (score -1):

By default, Spring will look in your current working directory for the directory named, `config`.  As you've noted, you're not executing the application in the directory containing the `config` directory.  You can override where Spring looks for this `config` folder with the `-Dspring.config.location` option or via the environment variable, `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION`

If your config directory is located at `/opt/myconfigs/config`, you would start your service with `-Dspring.config.location=/opt/myconfigs/config`.  Another option is to `export SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=/opt/myconfigs/config` and start your app without any additional JVM options.

If you're running tests in the application directory, then the config folder would be one level up from the current working directory.  Annotating your tests with
`@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.config.location=../config/,classpath:/application.properties")` would load the application.properties from both the config folder and the `src/main/resources` folder, properties in the config props would override properties in the local application properties.

The same thing can be achieved with the VM argument of `-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml,file:../config/`, here order is important.

Comment: Isn’t there any other way to do that? This approach would require me to take it out of the project.

Comment: can you take a look at the update?

Comment: AFAICT, this is not what OP wants. Your advise would result in the `application.properties` in the application to be ignored, whereas OP is looking to override it with the external `application.properties`.

Comment: @sbsatter If you want to keep the file inside your jar/war, simply add classpath:/ to the location.  Despite what the previous comment states, you can use this option to load both configurations.  It would look like this:

--spring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,classpath:/config/application.properties.  Or, you can omit the classpath from the config folder.  See the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Unfortunately, classpath:/config/application.properties is unable to lookup in parent module config folder (at least did not succeed in my attempts so far).

Comment: Despite what this answer claims, it is still wrong. A random config directory isn’t magically placed on the classpath. The `application.properties` gets copied to the root of `classes`, and hence present on the classpath.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar you're correct.  Then again, the answer doesn't state that any directory is added to the classpath.

Comment: @sbsatter You can point `spring.config.location` to any location on the filesystem so you wouldn't have to relocate the directory.  You can use either absolute or relative paths.  You can also achieve the same with `@TestPropertySources`, like this: `@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.config.location=../config/")`  This uses the relative path, pointing to the config location one level up from CWD, but it can be located anywhere on your filesystem.  Note the trailing slash; you must pass the trailing slash on directories.

Comment: @sbsatter please see the updates I made.  Hopefully this provides enough guidance to get you where you need to be

Answer (score -1):

If you want to override your `application.properties` with an external `application.properties`, you can copy the external file to `build/classes` directory using Gradle and append a profile name, like `application-ext.properties`. Then, activate `default` and `ext` profiles using `spring.profiles.active`.

Another option would be to use Spring Config server, but that may be overkill for this simple task.

Comment: This is a hacky solution, and will introduce the same issues once the same env properties are introduced in classpath.

Comment: @sbsatter Override by profiles is how Spring Cloud Config Server works, so, this is as clean a solution as they come. I've no idea what you mean, perhaps your concern will be clear to me if you can rephrase your statement.